# Sending the result of mux.Walk to ResponseWriter

Tags: http, go, gorilla

This is the first time I am writing any golang code and am building a basic web api. What I want to do is whenever a request is received on `"/"` path, I want to write out all the paths of `mux.Walk()` to my `ResponseWriter`. Since the `Walk` function takes an anonymous function, how can I make the handler wait until all the paths are calculated and entered into my array which I can send out? If not waiting, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `Walk` is a blocking call, there’s nothing to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the Walk function takes an anonymous function, how can I make
>   the handler wait until all the paths are calculated and entered into
>   my array which I can send out?

The output of the `Walk` function does not change, since you'll eventually end up with a static binary. In other words, you only need to get the ouput of the `Walk` function once.

> If not waiting, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Have a look at the [sample code](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#walking-routes) provided in the official github repository.

You can build your response for `walk` after the routes are first initialised, store this response locally, and return it once you receive a request for the available endpoints.